# How to consume from Kafka Spring Cloud Stream by default and also consume a Kafka message generated by the confluent API?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am building a microservice component which will consume by default Spring Cloud Stream (SCS) Kafka messages generated by other (SCS) components.

But I also have a requirement to consume Kafka messages from other components that are using the confluent API.

I have an example repository that shows what I'm trying to do.

https://github.com/donalthurley/KafkaConsumeScsAndConfluent

This is the application configuration below with the SCS input binding and the confluent input binding.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: kafka
  kafka:
    consumer:
      properties.schema.registry.url: http://192.168.99.100:8081
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: PLAINTEXT://192.168.99.100:9092
#          configuration:
#            specific:
#              avro:
#                reader: true
#            key:
#              deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
#            value:
#              deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer

      bindings:
        inputConfluent:
          contentType: application/*+avro
          destination: confluent-destination
          group: input-confluent-group
        inputScs:
          contentType: application/*+avro
          destination: scs-destination
          group: input-scs-group
```

With the above configuration I get both consumers created with the SCS default configuration
For instance the class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer is the value deserializer for both input bindings.

If I remove the comments in the above configuration I get both consumers with the configuration being sent from my Confluent client
For instance the class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer is the value deserializer for both input bindings.

I understand because the configuration is on the Kafka binder it will apply to all the consumers defined with that binder.

Is there any way that I can define those specific properties so that they will apply for only the confluent specific consumer binding and all the other input binding can use the default SCS config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set binding-specific consumer and producer properties via the `configuration` property.

See [the reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#kafka-consumer-properties).

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.configuration.foo.bar=baz
```

When using non-standard serializers/deserializers you must set `useNativeEncoding` and `useNativeDecoding` for producers and consumers respectively. Again, see the reference manual.

Comment: I made the above change as suggested with the configuration placed under  `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.inputConfluent.consumer.configuration` and setting `useNativeDecoding` and this worked.

See https://github.com/donalthurley/KafkaConsumeScsAndConfluent/commit/c763a32f0a6ec0099e4fad65f662fb09b06249b6

Comment: I think earlier when I was trying this earlier I was mixing up these two concepts  [consumer properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_consumer_properties) and [Kafka consumer properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#kafka-consumer-properties)

Comment: Right there are generic producer/consumer properties (common to all binders) and binder-specific producer/consumer properties.